# Integer sequence of chars from user-defined literal taking strings as parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, user-defined-literals

Currently, only doubles can produce a template of chars in a user defined literal:

```
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
// Later
1.3_x; // OK
"1.3"_y; // C++14 does not allow a _y user-
         // defined operator to parse that as a template of chars
```

Is there a clever way to produce a `std::integer_sequence` of chars using a user defined literal. In other words, what the code of `_y(const char*, std::size_t)` would be so that I end up with a `std::integer_sequence<char, '1', '.', '3'>`?

Comment: [N3599](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3599.html) may make it into C++1Z.

Comment: Do you really need an `integer_sequence`? This smells like an XY-problem.

Comment: @Columbo Where did you get that information? Last I heard it was rejected in EWG in favor of a `string_literal<N>`.

Comment: @T.C. Straight  [from the author](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/StaticPrintf.hxx#L929).

Comment: @Columbo Hmm, when was this?

Comment: There's a GNU extension for `template<typename CharT, CharT... Chars> stuff operator "" _x();` UDLs supported by gcc and clang in the meantime.

Comment: @T.C. https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#66 The machinery will be accepted by LEWG, and a revision of the paper (hopefully) accepted.

Comment: @Columbo IIRC it was reported that EWG chose N4121 (string_literal<N>, see EWG 139) over N4236 (which is an extension of N3599 and uses a parameter pack). Not clear whether we'd get the core language support with a pack if they don't want to provide library facilities.

Comment: @T.C. That's correct; i.e. one of them was chosen, which (if I remember Smith's mail correctly, which I can't check atm) is all EWG required (does that make sense?). Either way, there is (still) motivation, no disincentives, implementations that support it and barely any wording change necessary, I'm positive that a revised paper will be accepted.

Comment: @Columbo we'll see, I guess. I'm not sure they'd add a facility that produces parameter packs after rejecting something that actually uses said packs. Of course, I might be pleasantly surprised...

Comment: @T.C. They rejected the pack solution because the other one is better. That doesn't imply that string literal operator templates are useless, or that they wouldn't favor them. The code I linked requires it, and it's useful (I hope :D). Yeah, we'll see.

Comment: If you don't want to use compiler extensions, the closest thing I know of is used like this: `constexpr const char literal[] = "delta";
using X = make_char_sequence<sizeof(literal), literal>;`. Let me know if you're interested in details.

Comment: I am actually interested in details.

Comment: You should be able to expand the char pack into an array initializer: const char literal[]{Chars...};  You could even adda null at the end: char literal[]{Chars..., '\0'};

Comment: @Vincent Well, string literals can't be non-type template arguments, but namespace-scope constants can be. This is demonstrated in [\[temp.arg.nontype\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time, the best we can (portably) do is a macro trick as demonstrated [for `vtmpl::string`](https://github.com/Arcoth/VTMPL/blob/master/string.hxx#L34). Basically, we create a list of accesses such as

```
"abcd" -> {(0 < sizeof "abcd"? "abcd"[0] : 0), (1 < sizeof "abcd"? "abcd"[1] : 0), ...}
```

…which we trim to obtain the desired result.

The first step is easily done via [`BOOST_PP_ENUM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html), although  recursive macros are also fine (definition from [here](https://github.com/Arcoth/VTMPL/blob/master/macros.hxx#L11)):

```
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_1(s, x, m) m(s, x)
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_4(s, x, m)    VTMPL_SPLIT_1  (s, x, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_1  (s, x+1  , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_1  (s, x+2  , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_1  (s, x+3  , m)
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_16(s, x, m)   VTMPL_SPLIT_4  (s, x, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_4  (s, x+4  , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_4  (s, x+8  , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_4  (s, x+12 , m)
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_64(s, x, m)   VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+16 , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+32 , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+48 , m)
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x, m)  VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+64 , m), VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+128, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+194, m)
#define VTMPL_SPLIT_1024(s, x, m) VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+256, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+512, m), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+768, m)
```

Usage of the above looks like this (trimming included):

```
#define VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, n) vtmpl::rtrim<vtmpl::value_list<decltype(*str), VTMPL_SPLIT_##n(str, 0, VTMPL_ARRAY_SPLIT)>>::type
#
#define VTMPL_STRING(str) VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, 64  )
```

Where `rtrim` is defined in [`algorithms.hxx`](https://github.com/Arcoth/VTMPL/blob/master/algorithms.hxx#L122).