# Compile-time literal string as template argument

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr, string-literals

I'm trying to convert a C++ literal string into an instance of the following template:

```
template <char ... C>
struct string_literal {
    typedef string_constant type;
    static constexpr const char value[sizeof...(C)] = {C...};
    constexpr operator const char* (void) const {
        return value;
    }
};
template <char ... C>
constexpr const char string_literal<C...>::value[sizeof...(C)];
```

I came up with these helpers based on various sources for 'unpacking' the quoted string value into the template above.

```
template <unsigned N, const char (&S) [N], typename U>
struct selector;

template <unsigned N, const char (&S) [N], unsigned ...I>
struct selector<N, S, index_sequence<I...>> {
    using type = string_literal<S[I]...>;
};

template <unsigned N, const char (&S) [N]>
struct unpack {
    using type = typename selector<N, S, make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
};
```

However, when a call this I get a compiler error:

```
template <unsigned N>
constexpr auto make_string_literal(const char (&s) [N]) {
    return unpack<N, s>{}; // Error here
}

constexpr auto literal = make_string_literal("test");
// string_literal<'t','e','s','t','\0'>
```

GCC 4.9+ reports:
**error: 'const char (& s)[1]' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char (&)[1]' because a reference variable does not have a constant address**

Clang 3.7.1 reports:
**error: non-type template argument refers to object 's' that does not have linkage**

I tried a few different approaches but the errors are mostly the same.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You can use GNU extension ([example](https://github.com/tomilov/parser_generator/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L29)). It is the only way thinkable currently.

Comment: Alternate -unsatisfactory- solution that compiles under gcc and clang: http://ideone.com/uKP2qj

Comment: `(void)` is C-izm. `operator const char *` is currently wrong (error-prone): you may need to change definiton of `value` from `value[sizeof...(C)] = {C...};` to `value[sizeof...(C) + 1] = {C..., '\0'};`, because currently its correctness depends on way of acquisition of source char array.

Comment: Just to be clear @Orient. The deal of the sizeof+1 is to be sure that there's a null terminator for `operator const char*` even when the template is instantiated directly (i.e. `<'a', 'b', 'c'>`) instead of an initialization from a literal string that already has the null terminator. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I think so. Also `char a[3] = {'1', '2', '3'};` is possilbe case.

Comment: Your approach cannot work, because non-type template arguments are explicitly restricted [to not permit string literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1).

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35098061/3647361

Comment: It works if you remove all “_create” parts, ie Delete this whole fragment: > template <typename CharT, CharT... Cs>
> constexpr string_literal<Cs...> operator ""_create() > {
> return {};
> } and convert this (in main function)
string_literal<'t','e','s','t'> s = "test"_create; To this > string_literal<'t','e','s','t'> s;`
This is just a comment/reply to the answer of prestokeys

Answer (score 2):

Is this a satisfactory solution to meet your needs?

```
template <char ... C>
struct string_literal {
    static constexpr const char value[sizeof...(C)] = {C...};
    constexpr operator const char* (void) const {
        return value;
    }
    void foo() {std::cout << value << '\n';}
};
template <char ... C> constexpr const char string_literal<C...>::value[sizeof...(C)];

template <typename CharT, CharT... Cs>
constexpr string_literal<Cs...> operator ""_create() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    string_literal<'t','e','s','t'> s = "test"_create;
    std::cout << s << '\n';  // test
    s.foo();  // test
}
```

Comment: According to the comments of others, this depends on a GNU extension (constexpr user-defined literals) which is neither part of the current or the next C++ standard (so far): http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#66